# Configure RetryTemplate to test all failure codes except 404

Tags: java, spring, spring-retry

I am a little new to Spring Boot and am having trouble setting up my RetryTemplate to retry on all failed exception codes except 404. Below is my code:

```
@Bean
public RetryTemplate createRetryTemplate() {
    SimpleRetryPolicy retryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
    retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);

    UniformRandomBackOffPolicy backOffPolicy = new UniformRandomBackOffPolicy();
    backOffPolicy.setMinBackOffPeriod((long) minBackOffPeriod);
    backOffPolicy.setMaxBackOffPeriod(maxBackOffPeriod);

    RetryTemplate retryTemplate = new RetryTemplate();
    retryTemplate.setRetryPolicy(retryPolicy);
    retryTemplate.setBackOffPolicy(backOffPolicy);
    return retryTemplate;
}
```

I understand I need to create a policy but am unsure how to do so. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

I would try to use `ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy` to detect the type of the exception thrown and return different Retry Policies based on that:

```
class HttpStatusRetryPolicy extends ExceptionClassifierRetryPolicy {
    public HttpStatusRetryPolicy() {
        final NeverRetryPolicy doNotRetry = new NeverRetryPolicy();
        final SimpleRetryPolicy simpleRetryPolicy = new SimpleRetryPolicy();
        // configure your RetryPolicy here:
        // retryPolicy.setMaxAttempts(maxAttempts);
        // ...
        this.setExceptionClassifier(throwable -> {
            if (throwable instanceof HttpClientErrorException.NotFound) { // 404
                return doNotRetry;
            }
            return simpleRetryPolicy;
        });
    }
}
```